# Android — How to track bandwidth usage by application programmatically

Tags: android

I want measure bandwidth that my application used through mobile data or wifi?

I have seen there is a TrafficStats class from android API 8 , How can I use this in lower android API like from 4.

Is there any class or source code that can do this?

any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about logging how much data you send and receive to a database which you can later export? Or save to a file on SD card (if there is one).

Answer (score 2):

> I have seen there is a TrafficStats class from android API 8 , How can I use this in lower android API like from 4.

You can't, sorry.